# Trouble joining data.framesby ID

Tags: r, data.table

Joining two data.frames

```
data.table(df_del)
       KEY           place_Name
    1:  200039  BUFFALO/ROCHESTER   
    2:  200171  MILWAUKEE           
    3:  200197  PEORIA/SPRINGFLD.   
    4:  200233  OKLAHOMA CITY       
    5:  200272  LOS ANGELES      


data.table(df)
        firm_id brand_id   KEY UNITS DOLLARS       DATE
     1:     511      263  647840     1    7.29 2001-01-01
     2:     511      265  647840     2   14.58 2001-01-01
     3:     511      265  532733     1    6.39 2001-01-01
     4:      23      417  263939     1    4.79 2001-01-01
     5:      23      417  648768     5   24.45 2001-01-01
```

I am trying to join them by KEY but running into problems. The `df` file has approx 500,000 results and the `df_del` file has about 12,000.

The `df_del` file has the unique product key and it can be bought in the same city, so there may be 10 `KEY` values for one city(i.e. a product delivered 10 times in that city)

The `df`file also has the `KEY` column - however it is not always found. (when I copy a random `KEY`from the `df_del` dataframe and paste it in the search of the `df` frame I get no results sometimes. (This is because I am only using a snap shot of the `df` data and all of the `df_del` data). The alternative way i.e. `KEY`number from the `df`dataframe and pasted into the `df_del`gives me a result (can sometimes appear more than once in both data.frames)

My question;

When I try to run;

```
library(plyr)
df_test <- join(df, df_del,
     type = "left")
```

I obtain 500,000 results with all the `df` results but in the merged `place name` I get just NA values, I have tried, `right`, `left`, `inner`etc. I have also tried `merge(df, df_del, by = "KEY")` and get a result of zero.

Any help would be appreciated.

`df` should look like:

```
data.table(df)
        firm_id brand_id   KEY UNITS DOLLARS       DATE    place_name
     1:     511      263  647840     1    7.29 2001-01-01  NYC
     2:     511      265  647840     2   14.58 2001-01-01  NYC
     3:     511      265  532733     1    6.39 2001-01-01  Los Angeles
     4:      23      417  263939     1    4.79 2001-01-01  Chicago
     5:      23      417  648768     5   24.45 2001-01-01  Houston
```

Comment: Had you try :- 

library('dplyr')
results <- left_join(df,df_del,by="KEY")

Comment: yep,and BTW OP's data is inaccurate ..key col in df having different values as it appears in df_del's key col.

Answer (score 0):

you have a got a problem with your KEY column not matching. It could be because there is no common number like in my example

```
library(dplyr)
df_del <- data.table(KEY=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),place_name=c("NY","LONDON","PARIS","MELBOURNE","TOKYO","NY","LONDON","PARIS","MELBOURNE","TOKYO"))
df <- data.table(KEY=c(11,15,16,21,52)),UNITS=c(1,5,20,2,4))
merge(df,df_del,by="KEY")
```

> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: KEY,UNITS,place_name

```
left_join(df,df_del,by="KEY") 
KEY UNITS place_name  
1  11     1       <NA>
2  15     5       <NA>
3  16    20       <NA>
4  21     2       <NA>
5  52     4       <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Apologies I forgot to put matching ID numbers in both columns. (in the actual dataset there is matching KEYID rows).

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
   library(data.table)

df <- structure(list(is = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), firm_id = c(511, 511, 511, 
23, 23), brand_id = c(263, 265, 265, 417, 417), KEY = c(647840, 
647840, 532733, 263939, 648768), UNITS = c(1, 2, 1, 1, 5), DOLLARS = c(7.29, 
14.58, 6.39, 4.79, 24.45), DATE = c("2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", 
"2001-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2001-01-01")), .Names = c("is", 
"firm_id", "brand_id", "KEY", "UNITS", "DOLLARS", "DATE"), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))


df_del <- structure(list(KEY = c(200039, 200171, 200197, 200233, 200272, 647840, 532733, 263939, 648768
), place_Name = c("BUFFALO/ROCHESTER", "MILWAUKEE", "PEORIA/SPRINGFLD.", 
"OKLAHOMA CITY", "LOS ANGELES", "NYC", "Los Angeles", "Chicago", "Houston")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .Names = c("KEY", 
"place_Name"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Beauty of `data.table` is its concise syntax for joins.

```
setkey(df, KEY)
setkey(df_del, KEY)

df_del[df]
```

Produces the table you expected to see

```
      KEY  place_Name is firm_id brand_id UNITS DOLLARS       DATE
1: 263939     Chicago  4      23      417     1    4.79 2001-01-01
2: 532733 Los Angeles  3     511      265     1    6.39 2001-01-01
3: 647840         NYC  1     511      263     1    7.29 2001-01-01
4: 647840         NYC  2     511      265     2   14.58 2001-01-01
5: 648768     Houston  5      23      417     5   24.45 2001-01-01
```